# Divergence of $\int_{0}^{1/2}\frac{x^s-1}{-\log(x)}$

Tags: real-analysis, improper-integrals

I am interested in an integral $\int_{0}^{1/2}\frac{x^s-1}{-\log(x)}$ for $s \le -1$.

The lecture notes I am using claim that it diverges. I am not sure why.

I was trying to find a function $0 \le g \le \frac{x^s-1}{-\log(x)}$ on $(0,\frac{1}{2}]$ such that $\int_{0}^{1/2}g= \infty$. The only thing which comes to mind is $g=\frac{x^s-1}{\frac{1}{x}-1}$, but this apparently does not work e.g. for $s = -1$ (though seems to work for $s \le -2$).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Hint. Note that
$$\int_{0}^{1/2}\frac{x^s-1}{-\log(x)}\,dx =\int_{0}^{1/2}\frac{1}{x^{-s}(-\log(x))}\,dx+\int_{0}^{1/2}\frac{1}{\log(x)}\,dx\\\geq 
\int_{0}^{1/2}\frac{1}{x(-\log(x))}\,dx-\frac{1}{2\log(2)}.$$
Moreover
$$\int \frac{1}{x\log(x)}\,dx=\log(|\log(x)|)+C.$$
Can you take it from here?

Answer (score 1):

When $s\le-1$, we have
$$\frac{x^{s}-1}{-\log x}\ge\frac{x^{-1}-1}{-\log x}\ge\frac{1}{-2x\log x},$$
since $0<x<\frac{1}{2}$.

The antiderivative of the right-handed side is known, i.e. 
$$\int\frac{1}{-2x\log x}\mathrm{d}x= -\frac12\log|\log x|+C.$$
Hence, the integral diverges.

Comment: Not sure why did you start with $\frac{x^{-s}-1}{-\log(x)}$, we are supposed to deal with $\frac{x^{s}-1}{-\log(x)}$, right?

Comment: Sorry, that's a typo.

Answer (score 1):

$\newcommand{\bbx}[1]{\,\bbox[15px,border:1px groove navy]{\displaystyle{#1}}\,}
 \newcommand{\braces}[1]{\left\lbrace\,{#1}\,\right\rbrace}
 \newcommand{\bracks}[1]{\left\lbrack\,{#1}\,\right\rbrack}
 \newcommand{\dd}{\mathrm{d}}
 \newcommand{\ds}[1]{\displaystyle{#1}}
 \newcommand{\expo}[1]{\,\mathrm{e}^{#1}\,}
 \newcommand{\ic}{\mathrm{i}}
 \newcommand{\mc}[1]{\mathcal{#1}}
 \newcommand{\mrm}[1]{\mathrm{#1}}
 \newcommand{\pars}[1]{\left(\,{#1}\,\right)}
 \newcommand{\partiald}[3][]{\frac{\partial^{#1} #2}{\partial #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\root}[2][]{\,\sqrt[#1]{\,{#2}\,}\,}
 \newcommand{\totald}[3][]{\frac{\mathrm{d}^{#1} #2}{\mathrm{d} #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\verts}[1]{\left\vert\,{#1}\,\right\vert}$

> With
>   $\ds{\pars{%
> \begin{array}{rcl}
> \ds{x} & \ds{=} & \ds{\expo{-t}}
> \\
> \ds{t} & \ds{=} & \ds{-\ln\pars{x}}
> \end{array}}}$ and $\ds{\pars{s + 1 > 0 \implies s > - 1}}$:

\begin{align}
\int_{0}^{1/2}{x^{s} - 1 \over -\ln\pars{x}}\,\dd x & =
\int_{\infty}^{-\ln\pars{1/2}}{\expo{-st} - 1 \over t}\,\pars{-\expo{-t}}\dd t =
\int_{\ln\pars{2}}^{\infty}{\expo{-\pars{s + 1}t} - \expo{-t} \over t}\,\dd t
\\[1cm] & =
-\ln\pars{\ln\pars{2}}\bracks{\expo{-\pars{s + 1}\ln\pars{2}} - \expo{-\ln\pars{2}}}
\\[2mm] & -\int_{\ln\pars{2}}^{\infty}\ln\pars{t}\braces{\vphantom{\Large A}%
\expo{-\pars{s + 1}t}\left[\vphantom{\large A}-\pars{s + 1}\right] -
\expo{-t}\pars{-1}}\dd t
\\[1cm] & =
-\ln\pars{\ln\pars{2}}\pars{{1 \over 2^{s + 1}} - {1 \over 2}} +
\int_{\pars{s + 1}\ln\pars{2}}^{\infty}\ln\pars{t \over s + 1}\expo{-t}\,\dd t
\\[2mm] &
-\int_{\ln\pars{2}}^{\infty}\ln\pars{t}\expo{-t}\,\dd t
\\[5mm] & =
-\ln\pars{\ln\pars{2}}\pars{{1 \over 2^{s + 1}} - {1 \over 2}} -
{\ln\pars{s + 1} \over 2^{s + 1}} +
\int_{\pars{s + 1}\ln\pars{2}}^{\ln\pars{2}}\ln\pars{t}\expo{-t}\,\dd t
\\[5mm] & \stackrel{\mrm{as}\ s\ \to\ \pars{-1}^{+}}{\sim}\,\,\,
\bbx{-\ln\pars{s + 1} - {\ln\pars{\ln\pars{2}} \over 2} + \int_{0}^{\ln\pars{2}}
\ln\pars{t}\expo{-t}\,\dd t}
\end{align}

Comment: Should not the first equation be $\int_{0}^{1/2}\frac{x^s-1}{-\ln(x)} = \int_{-\infty}^{-\ln(1/2)}\frac{\exp(-st)-1}{t}(-\exp(-t))?$ The inverse function of $\exp(-t)$ is $-\ln(x)$.

Comment: @SergeyZykov Thanks. Indeed, there was a catastrophic error. I guess it's fixed right now.

Comment: I think you only have proofed that $\lim_{s \to -1, s > -1}\int_{0}^{1/2}\frac{x^s-1}{-\log(x)}=\infty$, but it is not what I was asking for. Or am I overlooking something?